# VBA - How to extend formula to last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extend through VBA a formula from the second cell to the last row of a specific column with this code:

```
    wsOrig.Range("E2").formula = "=XLOOKUP(A2,'LE_tested_for'!A:A, 'LE_tested_for'!G:G)"
    wsOrig.Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=wsOrig.Range("E2:E" & lastRowOrig),     Type:=xlFillDefault
```

the problem is that I only obtain the extension of the first value ("E2") for all the cells of the column and not the formula

Comment: This code works correctly. What outcome did you expect?

Comment: The problem is that also manually when I try to extende the formula to other cells basically copy the first cell value instead to run the XLOOKUP

Comment: Then show what data you have and what you would like to get. Apparently, the formula doesn't match the data.

Comment: It is unclear what you require. Let's say `lastRowOrig` is 5. Using your code, you will get 4  formulas. Do you want to keep the formulas? Do you want to replace the formulas with values? If you have MS 365, do you want to write a single formula into the first cell that will spill down? Share how you have calculated `lastRowOrig` (maybe you have calculated it in an empty column e.g. `E` instead of column `A`). Best the complete code.

Comment: Use a relative reference. Probably something like `wsOrig.Range("E2:E" & lastRowOrig).FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(RC[-4],LE_tested_for!C[-4], LE_tested_for!C[2])"`.